# Close a form when FormClosing cancels the event

Tags: windows, winforms

I am building an application that minimizes to tray when the user clicks the close button (the cross on the upper right corner) using this code:

```
private void FrmTest_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    e.Cancel = true;
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}
```

however, if I want to actually close the window on a button using `Close()` this handler is called and the form doesn't close.

How can I close my form / application now?

Comment: The context menu of the tray icon normally has an Exit menu entry, allowing the user to terminate your app.  Simply set a *bool* variable to true in your Click event handler, one you check in the FormClosing event handler.

Comment: @HansPassant in fact, the `CloseReason` works as well (see also my own answer)

Comment: It does not work when you call Close() in your Exit menu's Click event handler.

Comment: @HansPassant OK. I am in fact using `Application.Exit()` in those handlers, as opposed to `Close()` as in my question. If I just want to close the window and not exit, I'll use the boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it (thought I checked this, but apparently, something went amiss while debugging).

You can use the `CloseReason` property to find out why the event is called. When the user clicks on the close button on the window, `e.CloseReason` is `UserClosing`, otherwise it is `ApplicationExitCall`:

```
private void FrmTest_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) {
        e.Cancel = true;
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
}
```

**Update** when using `Close()` to close the form, the `CloseReason` will be the same and you should use a boolean as Hans Passant mentions in the comments. When using `Application.Exit()`, this `CloseReason` solution works.